# Значение списка с конца

Tags: python, list

Как узнать на каком месте с конца стоит 4-я цифра в списке? (это цифра 8 и она 11-я с конца)

```
[nan,nan,8,nan,6,nan,nan,9,nan,nan,nan,3,nan]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

nan = float('nan')
a = [nan, 1, 1, nan, nan, 9, 9, 9, 9, nan, nan]

def find_f(arr, c=4):
    c = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(arr[::-1]):
        if not math.isnan(e): c -= 1 
        if c == 0: return i
    return None

print(find_f(a)) # 5
```

Comment: А если последние 4 цифры вдруг не уникальны?

Comment: @GrAnd, поменял

Answer (score 0):

этот способ выводит место 4-й цифры с конца и саму цифру (правда здесь используется `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [None,None,8,None,6,None,None,9,None,None,None,3,None]

s = pd.Series(lst[::-1]).dropna().reset_index()
i,v = s.iloc[3].values.astype(int).tolist()

print(f'на месте {i+1} с конца стоит цифра {v}')  # на месте 11 с конца стоит цифра 8
```

**UPD**

без `pandas` даже проще можно:

```
nan = None
l = [nan, nan, nan, 8, 9, 9, 9, nan, nan]

i,v = [i for i in enumerate(l[::-1],1) if i[1]][3]
print(f'на месте {i} с конца стоит цифра {v}')  # на месте 6 с конца стоит цифра 8
```

Comment: @entithat, да вроде правильно работает "на месте 6 с конца стоит цифра 8", Как в вопросе - место 4-й цифры с конца. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Ну я говорю, что для списка, который я подал выше выводит *"на месте 4 с конца стоит цифра 9"*, а должно 8.

Comment: @entithat, видимо связано с тем, что в моем способе `nan` я заменил на `None` .

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = [np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan]
res= len(a) - np.nonzero(~np.isnan(a))[0][-1]
print(res)
```

> 2

Если нужно получить индекс значимого числа с конца pythonic way, то следует просто отнять единицу.